# C# select first item in datasource generated list

Tags: c#, listbox

I have this class

```
class UserData
{
    public UserData() { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Val { get; set; }
}
```

I have a normal ListBox. Im selecting Data from MySql.

```
private void ListUsers(string server)
{

    List<UserData> ls = new List<UserData>();

    foreach(dynamic obj in _data)
    {
        if(obj.servername == server)
        {
            ls.Add(new UserData() { Name = obj.username, Val = obj.password });
        }
    }
    UserList.Sorted = true;
    UserList.DisplayMember = "Name";
    UserList.ValueMember = "Val";
    UserList.DataSource = ls;
}
```

When debugging the `ls` it contains

```
[0] 
    Name => "Test",
    Val => "12345"
[1] 
    Name => "Test2",
    Val => "54321"
```

Now sometimes there ist only 1 postition in that list. If this happens, I want to select that entry or at least the `Name` and paste this into a textbox.

But for some reason I cant achive this. And Google didnt brought any results. At least non that suites to my problem.

I tried

```
rdpUserList.Items[0].ToString();
```

but this brings me `ProjectName.UserData` and not `Test`.

What is the right way to select the first Item in a list that was generated by a datasource ?

Comment: thank you very much. If you leave a Answere ill +vote and accept it! Im not the c# master, still lerning. So thx very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `ToString()` on an instance of the type `ProjectName.UserData`, which gives you its type name.

You want to access that instance's `Name` property instead.

If `rdpUserList` is a `List<UserData>`, you want this:

```
rdpUserList.Items[0].Name
```

If instead it's a datasource, you need to cast the item in order to access its properties:

```
((ProjectName.UserData)rdpUserList.Items[0]).Name
```

Comment: Never dealed with datasource since yet. So this really helped me. Of cource i tried to access the `Name` property before... but it resulted with an error because the property was unknown. Casting it helped. THX

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to this issue.   The first is a logical problem; you need to call the `Name` property and not the `ToString()` method.  Note that using this way, you need to cast to your object type.

`((UserData)rdpUserList.Items[0]).Name`

The second option is to override the `ToString()` method so you can call the name the way you tried.

```
class UserData
{
    public UserData() { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Val { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    { return this.Name; }
}
```

and then call with 
`rdpUserList.Items[0].ToString()`

Comment: i called ToString() because it was the only thing it showed and i saw it was wrong :)

Comment: That's because you didn't override it in your class.  `ToString()` returns the object type as a string when it hasn't been overridden.

Comment: I will suite with CodeCasters answere but you ill get +1 from here for showing more options. Thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for previous post, I did not test before I answered,

try the following if you want, I just like linq :)

```
var item = rdpUserList.Items.OfType<ListItem>().First();
Class1 t = new Class1(){Id=Convert.ToInt32(item.Value), description = item.Text};
```

OR for just the name

```
string name = rdpUserList.Items.OfType<ListItem>().First().Text;
```